# How can I efficiently and conveniently parse a simple message in Go?

Tags: parsing, go

Here's an example of a message:

```
User: tbone
Location: /whatever
Time: 23:23:23

This is a little message.
```

It's sort of HTTP- and other protocols-ish: headers followed by a blank line and the message body.

What's the easiest pretty efficient way to parse this? The standard [text/scanner](http://golang.org/pkg/text/scanner/) looks good to me. It would be very easy for me to use if I could deal with whitespace a little better. Namely, in the headers, it should ignore whitespace surrounding a colon, but let me know about spaces between words and newlines. I also need to know when the message body starts.

Might a scanner be the right tool for the job? Is there a better strategy? Should I just write my own little parser that marches along a character (or sometimes two) at a time and builds up my data structure? That's the kind of inconvenience I'd like to avoid, but I could do that.

By the way, I control the message format. Is there a better message format that would simplify the task?

Comment: I would add timezone information to the time -- this might save your neck if you'll need to go global or just one of communicating computers will misbehave due to its timezone misconfigured. I would just use a full datetime string like the `time.RFC3339` in the [`time`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/) core package. This package might be used for both formatting and parsing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

text/scanner would be way too much overhead (in programmer time) to use for a format this simple.

net/http uses [net/textproto](http://golang.org/pkg/net/textproto/), you might be able to use that too. Look for MIMEHeader and [ReadMIMEHeader](http://golang.org/pkg/net/textproto/#Reader.ReadMIMEHeader).

If you need something more complicated than what MIMEHeader can contain, I'd consider just using JSON.